# select records where field is empty

Tags: android, sqlite, is-empty

I need to select some columns from a table, where a certain column (pos_report_id in my case) is empty, not null. I tried this code in SQLiteDatabaseBrowser (for user_id='23') and it works fine:

```
"SELECT information_action.target_type, information_action.message_type,"
                + "information_action.start_date, information_action.end_date, information_action.content, information_action.status "
                + "FROM information_action INNER JOIN information_to_user ON "
                + "information_to_user.information_action_id = information_action.id_information_action "
                + "WHERE information_action.pos_report_id ='' AND information_to_user.user_id ='"
                + user_id + "'";
```

but in code, when I run the app I get this error :

```
ERROR   AndroidRuntime  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT information_action.target_type, information_action.message_type,information_action.start_date, information_action.end_date, information_action.content, information_action.status FROM information_action INNER JOIN information_to_user ON information_to_user.information_action_id = information_action.id_information_action WHERE information_action.pos_report_id ='' AND information_to_user.user_id ='23'
```

Any idea how to solve this ? why it's not ok with ''?

Answer (score 0):

Is user_id a char field in your database? Seems to be an integer. if this right remove the '' from 23.

Comment: the problem is not at user_id, it is at pos_report_id. I must check if pos_report_id is empty.

Answer (score 0):

In your query you used both `WHERE` and `ON` clause. try this one just small change, instead of WHERE use AND:

```
"SELECT information_action.target_type, information_action.message_type,"
                + "information_action.start_date, information_action.end_date, information_action.content, information_action.status "
                + "FROM information_action INNER JOIN information_to_user ON "
                + "information_to_user.information_action_id = information_action.id_information_action "
                + "AND information_action.pos_report_id ='' AND information_to_user.user_id ='"
                + user_id + "'";
```